# How to allow iframe embedding only for whitelisted websites?

Tags: php, html, forms, iframe, referer

I've a form that I'd like to embed in a website, which is on my whitelist.

Other websites, that try to embed it, should get only an error page.

```
<iframe src="https://domain.tld/getForm.php?embed=1&formId=123456"></iframe>
```

I was hoping that I could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in `getForm.php` to check the embeding website, but it's not working.

Does anyone know a best practise or any workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to check the IP of the remote address making the request to `getForm.php`  however, IPs can be spoofed.  Look at `$_SERVER` supper global.  I would think that the `REMOTE_ADDR` would be the IP of the site making the call, but I am not 100% sure, that may just be the clients IP.

Comment: could you find a solution for this? I tried $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and it works fine but I read somewhere it can be spoofed, so is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most browsers will support the X-Frame-Options header.

This header will prevent access:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

And this header to allow access:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM [uri]
```

Examples for the options:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
```

An example in PHP:

```
<?php header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN'); ?>
```

You can read further here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Hope it helps a bit!

Comment: `allow-from` is obselete now

Comment: Is there another way to allow from specific domain as allow-from is obselete.

Comment: you may use `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' yoursites;`

Answer (score 42):

Content Security Policy headers are now the recommended approach.

Example from MDN:

```
// iframe can be embedded in pages on the origin and also on https://www.example.org
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.example.org;
```

For more details see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Comment: just to help other I have to set it in this way in my apache conf.

Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https://iframetester.com;"

Comment: NB it does NOT inherit from default-src :*(